# Gradle JavaExec complains about not being able to load or find main class

Tags: java, gradle, javaexec-gradle-plugin

I'm writing a simple Gradle task to launch a java application in my build.gradle file. When I try to run the task with the `--info` flag, it outputs the java command as follows:

```
<JAVA_HOME>/bin/java -Xmx256M
   -cp <ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_ALL_LIBS>/launcherLib/launcherLib.jar:
   <ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_ALL_LIBS>/lib1/lib1.jar 
   com.hungryTux.launcher.LauncherClass 'launcherArg'
```

Gradle then complains about not being able to load or find the main class. I know that the `com.hungryTux.launcher.LauncherClass` class is present in the `launcherLib` jar file specified in the classpath and has a `main` method in it. The exact error message is `Error: Could not find or load main class`.

What's even more amusing is that, if I were to take this command from the Gradle tasks's output and try to run it directly on the terminal, it appears to find the main class and launch the application correctly.

The working directory for this Gradle task is the root of my project containing the `build.gradle` file. When I try to run the command manually, I do it from the same directory.

I feel I'm missing something obvious with the way JavaExec task works. I've read the documentation for it, but nothing really rings a bell.

I should point out though that the `com.hungryTux.launcher.LauncherClass` class is not specified as the `Main-Class` in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file contained in the `launcherLib.jar` file. Could this be an issue? If so, how does this work when run from the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a parsing issues with one of the jvmArgs I was passing to JavaExec. Getting rid of the offending argument got things working.